# Azure Service Bus for ABP framework

Tags: azureservicebus, abp, event-bus

I have downloaded the latest source code from the Github repository and I successfully build the ABP framework and Azure Event bus sample code. I configured the azure connection string, topic name, and subscription. When I run the project, it throws the stack overflow exception. I debug the code and found the following issues.

```
public async Task PublishAsync(
        Type eventType,
        object eventData,
        bool onUnitOfWorkComplete = true,
        bool useOutbox = true)
    {
        if (onUnitOfWorkComplete && UnitOfWorkManager.Current != null)
        {
            AddToUnitOfWork(
                UnitOfWorkManager.Current,
                new UnitOfWorkEventRecord(eventType, eventData, EventOrderGenerator.GetNext(), useOutbox)
            );
            return;
        }
        if (useOutbox)
        {
            if (await AddToOutboxAsync(eventType, eventData))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        await PublishToEventBusAsync(eventType, eventData);
    }
```

In the above code, the value of UnitOfWorkManager.Current is null so it jumps to the second condition, and executes the AddToOutboxAsync method.

```
private async Task<bool> AddToOutboxAsync(Type eventType, object eventData)
    {
        var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkManager.Current;
        if (unitOfWork == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (var outboxConfig in AbpDistributedEventBusOptions.Outboxes.Values)
        {
            if (outboxConfig.Selector == null || outboxConfig.Selector(eventType))
            {
                var eventOutbox = (IEventOutbox)unitOfWork.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(outboxConfig.ImplementationType);
                var eventName = EventNameAttribute.GetNameOrDefault(eventType);
                await eventOutbox.EnqueueAsync(
                    new OutgoingEventInfo(
                        GuidGenerator.Create(),
                        eventName,
                        Serialize(eventData),
                        Clock.Now
                    )
                );
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Again, in the above method, it checks the unit of work which is null so it returns false and PublishToEventBusAsync is executing and that method again calls the first publish method so the code executing into the loop and throws stack overflow exception.

I also tried to read the documents on azure event bus the link redirects to 404 page.

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.0/Distributed-Event-Bus-Azure-Integration

Is something missing in the configuration to get the unit of work object?

Thanks
Imrankhan

Comment: As you have already opened an issue on GitHub, adding reference to help other community members. You can refer to [Message is not publishing in Azure service bus samples code](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/10722)

Comment: As you have already resolved the issue as per this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/10722#issuecomment-982505579), I would suggest you to add the answer here and accept it so that it will be beneficial to other community members who might face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the latest changes and the issue was resolved.